# How to erase the inner map's key and then erase outer map element in C++

Tags: c++

I have a map like this:

```
std::map<int, std::map<float, char>> m;
```

In this I need to delete the inner map's key, which is a float value. And after erasing that, if the inner map is empty then erase that element from the outer map also.

One example.

```
std::map<int, std::map<float, char>> m;
std::map<float, char> m1;
m1[2.5] = 'c';
m[5] = m1;
```

Key to erase from the inner map is `2.5`. After erasing this key from the inner map, it becomes empty.

Now the outer map needs to check that after each erase if the inner map is empty then erase the element from the outer loop also.

Now key `2.5` from the inner map has to be erased first.

Comment: why don't you just iterate over outer map and see if m.second is empty then delete m.first

Comment: Presumably you'd find the item you want to delete by iterating through the outer map since you're looking for a value and not a key, or maybe you know the key in the outer map. `std::map::erase` works with either, so it seems like removing the entry would be simple.

Comment: I know only the key of the inner map.

Comment: @sureshm why do you not know the key of the outer map? You needed it to insert the inner map into the outer map to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in comments, you only know the key in the inner map (why do you not know the key in the outer map?), in which case you have no choice but to iterate the entire outer map until you find an element whose inner map contains that key. Then you will know which outer element you can erase. For example:

```
std::map<int, std::map<float, char>> m;
m[5][2.5] = 'c';
...
for(auto m_iter = m.begin(); m_iter != m.end(); ++m_iter)
{
    auto &m2 = m_iter->second;
    auto m2_iter = m2.find(2.5);
    if (m2_iter != m2.end())
    {
        m2.erase(m2_iter);
        if (m2.empty())
            m.erase(m_iter);
        break;
    }
}
```